# I can not center my div using jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used this jQuery script to center my div based on browsers window resolution. However I can't get it working. What am I missing here?

I posted it in jsFiddle for better understanding here http://jsfiddle.net/9wvt3/

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
$(#main).center();
```

Comment: This: `$(#main).center();` should probably be `$('#main').center();`. Note the `'` in the `$()` function argument.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think you're right on that: http://jsfiddle.net/QYkTy/  You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Joseph - Thanks. I added it as an answer; I wonder sometimes if I'm not missing something. `:)`

Comment: Why not just use CSS to center the element ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
$(#main).center();
```

Should probably be:

```
$('#main').center();
```

Note the `'` in the `$()` function argument.

Comment: True I missed that. I am accepting it in 5 minutes.. well in 4. I noticed that if I play with the browser size after the page is load it does not centers. What should I do about this ?

Comment: It's because you're setting absolute top and left value of the `div`, which means it won't change on `resize`. What to do about it would have to do with the overall usage you had in the page, but you should set a [`resize`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) handler at least.

Answer (score 3):

You are simply missing the quotes on `#main` within `$('#main').center();`

http://jsfiddle.net/9wvt3/2/